# Display input box in Iron Python

Tags: python, ipython

I am trying to display a message box with OK and cancel buttons in Iron Python. Coding used is:

```
WinForms.MessageBox.Show("Hello, world!", "MessageBoxHelloWorld",WinForms.MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,WinForms.MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
```

but I want to display an input box that asks user whether to continue or not. depending on the response I have to perform next steps. message box code above shows only ok and cancel buttons, where I need to have Continue and Close buttons and take this input in some variable so that I can perform next steps based on this condition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create a messagebox with following command

```
WinForms.MessageBox.Show()
```

but how do I specify current object in it's arguments?

```
MessageBox.Show Method (IWin32Window, String, String, MessageBoxButtons)
```

I need to specify IWin32Window argument here.